# how to identify submit() that arrived from javascript method(not button) in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a list of users that in the end of each line in the table I added two links("href"):
one for "update" user and secend for "delete" user.
So for enable that I added a call to javascript function that capture the ID of user
and insert it to some form that I created before (form with only one "hidden" field),
and then the function activated submit() operation to the server part (asp.net code).

I checked and the submit() operation works ok(checked with respons.write()...)

But I know how to recognize a submit form button inside IsPost by ask what the value 
of the submit button (for example: if(Request.Form["ExpertButton"]== "delete"){..some code here....})

But when I activate submit() with javascript, how could I recognize post?
I tryed with the value of the hiiden field but it's not capture this 
and it skiped of the if statement....

the list of users code:

```
foreach(var row in db.Query(displayExperts,nameOfExpert))
                {
                <tr>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.ExpertID</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.name</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.password</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.allowBonds</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.allowStocks</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.allowExchangeTraded</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.allowMutualFund</td>
                     <td class="dispExpertActScreen"><a href="#" onclick="expertToDelete('@row.ExpertID') ;return false;" style="color: #b04e4e">update</a></td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen"><a href="#" onclick="expertToDelete('@row.ExpertID') ;return false;" style="color: #b04e4e">delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                }
```

the form code:

```
<form method="post" name="deleteExpert" style="font-size: medium; margin-top: 10%" dir="rtl">
    <input type="hidden" name="expertID" id="expertID" value="">
</form>
```

the javascript code:

```
<script>

    function expertToDelete(expertID) {

        document.getElementById('expertID').value = expertID;
        document.getElementById('deleteExpert').submit ();
    }


</script>
```

the asp.net code:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("MyProjectSite");
    var display="no";
    var displayExperts="";
    var nameOfExpert="";
    var category="";
     if(IsPost)
    {
        if(Request.Form["ExpertButton"]== "search")// this is by button!!!
        {
             some code.....

        }

       //Response.Write("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
        if(Request.Form["ExpertButton"] != "")// this need to be by javascript submit() method !!! here I need to recognize it.
        {
           var id=Request.Form["expertID"];
           Response.Write("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"+id);
           var deleteQuery="DELETE FROM InvestmanExperts WHERE ExpertID=@0";
           db.Execute(deleteQuery,id);
        }
    }
    db.Close();
}
```

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not puting another hidden input value :

```
<input type="hidden" name="txtJavascriptMode" id="txtJavascriptMode" value="">
```

then in your javascript code :

```
<script>
    function expertToDelete(expertID) {

        document.getElementById('expertID').value = expertID;
        document.getElementById('txtJavascriptMode').value = 'true';
        document.getElementById('deleteExpert').submit ();
    }
</script>
```

and in your serverside you can checkout

```
if(Request["txtJavascriptMode"] == "true")
{}
```

Comment: hay thanks.. but there is strange problem. if I add before the if(Request["txtJavascriptMode"] == "true") response.write("-----"+Request["txtJavascriptMode"]); it's working if I delete this sentence it's not working.... why?