# how to identify submit() from javascript function and why it's not works

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a list of users that in the end of each line in the table I added two links("href"): one for "update" user and secend for "delete" user. So for enable that I added a call to javascript function that capture the ID of user and set another field to "true" and insert these values to some form that I created before (form with only two "hidden" field), and then the function activated submit() operation to the server part (asp.net code).

I checked and the submit() operation works ok(checked with respons.write("-----")...)

But I know how to recognize a submit form button inside IsPost by ask what the value of the submit button (for example: if(Request.Form["ExpertButton"]== "delete"){..some code here....})

But when I activate submit() with javascript, how could I recognize post? I tryed with the value of the hidden field but it's not capture this and it skiped of the if statement....

another problem that I found with debug is that the browser(IE9) throw error when the function
submit() happens...

the list of users code:

```
foreach(var row in db.Query(displayExperts,nameOfExpert))
                {
                <tr>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.ExpertID</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.name</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.password</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.allowBonds</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.allowStocks</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.allowExchangeTraded</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.allowMutualFund</td>
                     <td class="dispExpertActScreen"><a href="#" onclick="expertToDelete('@row.ExpertID') ;return false;" style="color: #b04e4e">update</a></td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen"><a href="#" onclick="expertToDelete('@row.ExpertID') ;return false;" style="color: #b04e4e">delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                }
```

the form:

```
<form method="post" name="deleteExpert" style="font-size: medium; margin-top: 10%" dir="rtl">
    <input type="hidden" name="expertID" id="expertID" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="txtJavascriptMode" id="txtJavascriptMode" value="">
</form>
```

the function:

```
<script>

    function expertToDelete(expertID) {

        document.getElementById('expertID').value = expertID;
        document.getElementById('txtJavascriptMode').value = 'true';
        document.getElementById('deleteExpert').submit();
    }

</script>
```

the asp.net code:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("MyProjectSite");
    var display="no";
    var displayExperts="";
    var nameOfExpert="";
    var category="";
     if(IsPost)
    {
        if(Request.Form["ExpertButton"]== "search")// this is by button!!!
        {
             some code.....

        }

        Response.Write("----");
         if(Request.Form["txtJavascriptMode"] == "true")
         {
            var id=Request.Form["expertID"];
            var deleteQuery="DELETE FROM InvestmanExperts WHERE ExpertID=@0";
            db.Execute(deleteQuery,id);
         }
    }
    db.Close();
}
```

Another strange somthing is when I put this line:

```
Response.Write("----"+Request.Form["txtJavascriptMode"]);
```

before:

```
if(Request.Form["txtJavascriptMode"] == "true");
```

the website indentation looks bad but the delete line of user works OK, why?

thanks...

Comment: Also, why are you asking **[the EXACT same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667848/how-to-identify-submit-that-arrived-from-javascript-methodnot-button-in-asp)** again?? You just asked that 3 hours ago...

Comment: @Blachshma, when you see that flag (*for closing*) the question as exact duplicate

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I did... :)

Comment: @Blachshma hmm.. i only see my own flag..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Tried again, it says I already flagged it... go figure...

Comment: @Blachshma, ok you need 3K reputation to directly flag questions. see http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions since you do not have it your flag needs approval by the community..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden field are supposed to be working fine. Try adding id `deleteExpert` to your form.